# "the hotel where you stayed" or "the hotel where you stayed at"

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, formality

Which sentence is correct?

> 1.​ Did you like the hotel where you stayed?
>   2.​ Did you like the hotel where you stayed **at**?

I am curious as to whether to use ***at*** or not.

Comment: The first sentence is correct, and is a common construction.

Comment: @ADAM : What about second sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is correct.

> Do you like the hotel where you stayed?

If you didn't have the "where," however, you could get away with including the "at."

> Do you like the hotel you stayed at?

That has a dangling participle, and would more grammatically correctly be phrased

> Do you like the hotel at which you stayed?

Although that's way more formal than how anyone would probably speak in real life.

I think the difference between the two you said becomes a bit more evident when you change it around a bit.

> Where did you say last night?

That sounds a lot more comfortable than its equivalent

> Where did you stay *at* last night?

Of course, you could also say:

> Which hotel did you stay at last night?

And that would be reasonable.

It's ultimately just a choice between "where" and "at which."

Comment: *Do you like the hotel you stayed at?* There is no dangling participle in this sentence, and you have changed the tense of auxiliary DO. *Do you like the hotel at which you staued?8 is not 'more grammatically correct'. It is merely more formal. See my answer below.

Do you like the hotel at which you stayed?

Answer (score 2):

*1.Did you like the hotel where you stayed?*

This is correct. The relative pronoun *where* has the meaning of *at/in/to which.*

*2.Did you like the hotel where you stayed at?*

As the *where* contains within itself the idea of *at*, the *at* in your sentence is redundant, and the sentence is incorrect. You can say:

*3. Did you like the hotel you stayed at/in?*

or

*4. Did you like the hotel at/in which you stayed?*

No. 4 is rather formal.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add "at" here; it sound redundant, if not grammatically incorrect.

Comment: What is it make you think for redundant you are?